# Let $Z\in \mathcal{N}(0,I)$, and $A$ be a permutation of $B$. Then $P(Z+x \in A) \ge P(Z+x \in B)$ if $x \in A$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$  such that $A$ is permutation of $B$.  Now let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a standard normal.   Can we show that 
\begin{align}
P(Z+x \in A) \ge  P(Z+x \in B)
\end{align}
if $x\in A$?

I think the key here is that $P(Z \in A) =P (Z\in B)$.

Comment: A set $A$ is permutation of a set  $B$,  if there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A=\{ Px: x\in B \}$.

**Equvalent reformulation:**
Let $A=\mathsf{P} B$ where $\mathsf{P}$ is some permutation matirx 
\begin{align}
P(Z+x \in A) \ge P(Z+y \in A)
\end{align}
where $x\in A$ and $y $ is a permuation of $x$ (i.e., $\mathsf{P}y=x$).

This follows since
\begin{align}
P(Z+x \in B)= P(Z+x \in PB)=P(Z+y \in A). 
\end{align}
where we used that $\mathsf{P}Z=Z$ in distribuiton.

If needed, please assume that $A\cap B= \emptyset$ or set of measure zero.

**My attempt:**  I will attempt to shows the alternative.
Let $A_x=A-x$ and $A_y=A-y$ 
\begin{align}
P(Z \in A_x \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r) ) \ge  P(Z \in A_y \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r)) )
\end{align}

Claim:   $A_y \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r) \subseteq A_x \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r)$ for all $r$.

Then,  taking $r \to \infty$ we have that 
\begin{align}
P(Z \in A_x  )=\lim_{r \to \infty} P(Z \in A_x \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r) ) \ge  \lim_{r \to \infty}  P(Z \in A_y \cap \mathcal{B}(0,r)) )=P(Z \in A_y  )
\end{align}

So, everything boils down to showing this claim.

Comment: Why do you think it would be true?

Comment: @fGDu94  First, because of $P(Z \in A) =P (Z\in B)$.  Second, since we move $Z$ more towards $A$

Comment: $x\in A \implies x\in B$. How does adding x to Z affect the probability?

Comment: @ShivTavker  It is not true that $x\in A$ implies that $x\in B$.

Comment: Oops sorry for that. Can we express permutation of set geometrically? If they are symmetrical about origin or line passing through origin That would definitely make the statement true, from ur argument of $Z$ moving towards $A$.

Comment: @ShivTavker  yeah. I would like to show this only with the premutation assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, and $A, B$ can be arbitrary shapes, then the conjecture is false.

Consider $n=2$ and the permutation that swaps $x,y$ coordinates (aka, reflection across $45^\circ$ line).

Let $A = \mathcal{B}((5,0), 1) \cup \mathcal{B}((0,5), 2)$, then $B = \mathcal{B}((5,0), 2) \cup \mathcal{B}((0,5), 1)$.  Now take $x = (5,0)$.  This $x$ is in the smaller ball of $A$ but in the bigger ball of $B$, so $P(Z + x \in A) < P(Z + x \in B)$.

Comment: What does your notation mean $\mathcal{B}((5,0),1) \cup \mathcal{B}((5,0),2)$?

Comment: I follow this now.  Thank you. Yes, this a counterexample.     Do you think a convexity assumption would make this true?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(x,r)$ it the ball centered at $x$ or radius $r$ (I thought that's what you meant in your OP).  Anyway, I don't think convexity would fix this.  Just consider the convex closure of $A, B$ above, which will be a sort of egg shape.  It is still true that $x$ is at the "pointy" end of the $A$ egg and the "fat" end of the $B$ egg.  In fact, even imposing $x \in A, x \notin B$ won't help, coz $x$ can be just inside the pointy end of $A$, but just outside the fat end of $B$, leading to $P(Z+x \in A) < P(Z+x \in B) \approx 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Are correct with this.

Comment: You might be interested in somewhat related question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664365/a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-b-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-2-le-x-1-le-x-3