# $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1\le x_2 \le x_3 \}, B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_2\le x_1 \le x_3 \}$. Show $P(Z+\mu \in A) \ge P(Z+ \mu \in B)$ for $\mu \in A$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let  $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):  x_1\le x_2 \le x_3 \}$ and $B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):  x_2\le x_1 \le x_3 \}$.

Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a standard normal random vector.

I am trying to see if the following inequality holds:
\begin{align}
P(Z+\mu \in  A) \ge  P(Z +\mu\in B),
\end{align} 
for all $\mu \in A$.

**Here is the proof that I tried that doesn't work**
\begin{align}
P(Z+\mu \in  A)& \ge  P(Z \in  A)\\
&= P(Z \in  B)\\
&\ge P(Z+\mu \in  B).
\end{align}

The first inequality and equality are true.  However, the last inequality does not hold as was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664244/let-z-in-mathcaln0-i-and-a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-show).

Nonetheless, I think the inequality is true. This is also related to another question I asked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660745/let-z-in-mathcaln0-i-and-a-be-a-permutation-of-b-then-pzx-in-a)

Comment: BTW, this is part of an interesting _series_ of questions you have posted.  May I ask, where do they come from?  What's the background?

Comment: Sure. I actually stumbled on one of them as an exam question. However, I started to think about how these inequalities can be generalized.   It completely changed my intuition about things. I like them because it combines nice geometric properties also things that happen here will not happen in dimension two.

Comment: Yeah, these are in essence geometry problems rather than probability problems.  And I couldnt solve this one until I finally succeeded in visualizing A and B -- by picking up a takeout menu, folding it along the center line at a right angle (a sort of V shape), then tilting it a bit.  :) Once I did that, the $|\mu - a| \le |\mu - b|$ lemma is obvious.

Comment: I was trying to prove your lemma for arbitrary cones. I don't see a simple solution. I will try to ask it later on this platform.

Comment: Geometrically, I think the "partnering" you need is the reflection that maps one cone rigidly to the other.  Then I imagine it should be true that $|\mu - b| \ge |\mu - a|$

Comment: Why you say rigidly, what do you mean?

Comment: I am not good with the formal terms.  What I meant is... distance & angle preserving?  In fact, forget I said rigid.  Reflection is really what is needed (I think) and A, B dont even have to be cones, or even convex.  (Need to think more to confirm this, might write more later.)

Comment: Thanks!!! This is very interesting discussion.

Comment: I asked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665425/let-c-1-c-2-be-two-congruent-cones-with-tips-at-zero-x-ty-le-x-y      Let me know if I phrased it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is true, but the shapes of $A$ and $B$ are just weird enough that I can't find a way to prove this by transforming $\mu$ or $Z$.  Instead I had to transform the destination.

Let $\mu = (c_1, c_2, c_3) \in A$, and consider some $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3) \in B$.  Its "transformed partner" is $a = T(b) = (b_2, b_1, b_3) \in A$.  The key is:

**Lemma:** $|\mu - a| \le |\mu - b|$.

**Proof:**

$$|\mu - a|^2 = (c_1 - b_2)^2 + (c_2 - b_1)^2 + (c_3 - b_3)^2$$

$$|\mu - b|^2 = (c_1 - b_1)^2 + (c_2 - b_2)^2 + (c_3 - b_3)^2$$

$$|\mu - a|^2 - |\mu - b|^2 = -2c_1 b_2 -2c_2 b_1 + 2 c_1 b_1 + 2 c_2 b_2 = -2(c_2 - c_1)(b_1 - b_2) \le 0$$

where the last inequality comes from $c_2 \ge c_1 (\mu \in A), b_1 \ge b_2 (b \in B).  \square$

Now since the $T()$ mapping is bijective, measure-preserving, rigid, etc., the claim follows:

$$P(Z + \mu \in B) = \iiint_B \phi(|\mu - b|) \,db \le \iiint_A \phi(|\mu - a|) \,da = P(Z + \mu \in A)$$

where $\phi()$ is the pdf for vector $Z$, and I have written it in a form to highlight the fact that it only depends on $|Z|$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about inequality.   First, use monotonicity of $\phi$ to show that $\int_B \phi(|\mu-b|) \le  \int_B \phi(|\mu-a|)$, right?  How do you make the next transition from $\int_B \phi(|\mu-a|)$ to $\int_A \phi(|\mu-a|)$ ?

Comment: I think I follow now. You use the fact that $T$ is measure-preserving and bijective.

Comment: yeah, that part is a bit hand-wavy, sorry! :)   to do it perfectly formally probably requires a Jacobian in there, and i'm not very good with those.  in short, the geometric intuition is more obvious than writing it out as an integral.

Comment: Do you think this inequality holds if $A$ and $B$ are cones (starting at zero) that are permutations of each other?   In this case, $A$ and $B$ are indeed cones that are permutations of each other.

Comment: I imagine the inequality holds if they are congruent, non-overlapping cones (not necessarily permutations), with the tip at the origin.  One way the inequality breaks is e.g. if A has a pointy end _that points at a flat side of_ B, so that $\mu \in A$ lives near the pointy end of A and its neighborhood has "more B than A" in it.

Comment: Great. This what I was thinking. That is they have the same spherical measure and the tips are at zero, then the same inequality should hold.

Comment: By the way, in case you are interested here is a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761273/show-that-e-left-v-2-vu-u-in-c-times-c-right-e-left-v-2-righ