# Let $C_1,C_2$ be two congruent cones with tips at zero. Show $\| x-T(y)\| \le \|x-y\|$ where $x\in C_1, y \in C_2, T: C_2 \to C_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Let $C_1,C_2$ be two congruent and non-overlapping cones with tips at zero.  Let $T:C_2 \to C_1$ be a map from $C_1$ to $C_2$ which is just a rotation.

Does the following inequality hold for $x\in C_1, y \in C_2$
\begin{align}
\| x-T(y)\| \le \|x-y\|
\end{align}

It would be good to have a general proof without specifying dimensions of the vectors. However, proof in dimension three would be acceptable.

This question was inspired by a discussion I had [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664365/a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-b-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-2-le-x-1-le-x-3) with  @antkam.

My attempt: 
\begin{align}
\| x-T(y)\|^2 -\|x-y\|^2&= -2 \langle x,T(y) \rangle + 2 \langle x,y \rangle \\
&= 2 \langle x,y-T(y) \rangle \\
\end{align}
Not sure how to show that the inner product is negative.

**Edit:**  As pointed in one of the answers, the inequality is not true in general and we need a reflection property. Therefore, let's prove this under the reflection assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true if $T$ is a *rotation* between the two cones.  Consider e.g. the 2-D plane and $C_1$ is $0 \le \theta \le 90$ (degrees, for convenience), and $C_2$ is $100 \le \theta \le 190$.  Then $y = (r, 110) \in C_2 $ maps to $T(y) = (r, 10) \in C_1$ and $x = (r, 80) \in C_1$ is closer to $y$ than to $T(y)$.

This is however true if $T$ is a *reflection* between the two cones.  In fact $C_1, C_2$ do not have to be cones -- they only need to be reflections of each other, and their convex closures must not overlap (they don't need to be convex themselves).  In this case, the (hyper)plane of reflection $P$ separates the two objects.

Consider the triangle $Q$ formed by $y, T(y), x$.  Since $y$ and $T(y)$ are mirror images across $P$, the line segment $P \cap Q$ is the perpendicular bisector of the triangle base segment from $y$ to $T(y)$, and $x$ is on the $T(y)$ side of the bisector, so it is closer to $T(y)$ than to $y$.

Comment: Would sets  $C_1=\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \}$ and $C_2=\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3): x_3 \le x_2 \le x_1\}$ have this reflection property?  I am thinkig of exmaples

Comment: I think so...  you're swapping the $x$- and $z$- axes, so that's a reflection across the $45$ degree line $x=z$ in the $(x,z)$ plane, or in 3-D, a reflection across the $x=z$ plane.  In fact this answer also works on your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664365/a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-b-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-2-le-x-1-le-x-3/3665218#3665218)

Comment: Thanks. One thing, how do you define the reflection? I wanted to see if I can finish my inner product proof?

Comment: The plane of reflection is defined by $\hat{n} \cdot p = $ some constant $c$, where $\hat{n}$ is the normal vector.  You can say e.g. $C_1$ is on the side $\hat{n} \cdot p > c$ and $C_2$ is on the $< c$ side.  Then $y - T(y) = a \hat{n}$ for some _negative_ scalar $a$, and $x \cdot (y - T(y)) < 0$ can be shown by decomposing $x$ into a component on the plane and the perpendicular component $b \hat{n}$ for some _positive_ scalar $b$.